# Data from sql table will not be passed over to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

i have a Python project, where i want to readout data from a sql table, pass this data to a pandas dataframe and afterwards analyse and plot the data.
The problem i have is, that some data will not be passed to the panday dataframe and i do no know why.

I have no clue how to solve this issue.

Here is my code:
`

```
# Get transaction data grouped by category
sql_query_trans_cat = pd.read_sql_query ('''
                               SELECT
                               category_in_out_id,
                               SUM (amount)
                               FROM Transactions
                               GROUP BY category_in_out_id
                               ''', conn)

print(f"------------->> DEBUG Output of sql_query_trans_cat <<---------------------\n{sql_query_trans_cat}")

# Create a dataframe for all the transactions to be stored
df_trans_all = pd.DataFrame(sql_query_trans_all, columns = ['id', 'hash', 'valutadate', 'amount', 'transaction_text_id',
                                        'account_id', 'asset_class_id', 'category_in_out_id', 'currency_id', 'int_or_ext_id', 'remarks'])

# Create a dataframe for the transactions grouped  by catagory
df_trans_cat = pd.DataFrame(sql_query_trans_cat, columns = ['amount', 'category_in_out_id'])

print(f"------------->> DEBUG Output of df_trans_cat <<---------------------\n{df_trans_cat}")
print(f"------------->> DEBUG Output of df_trans_cat Data Types <<---------------------\n{df_trans_cat.dtypes}")
```

`

Please see also attached picture for more information.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpM3Y.png)

I have checked if the datatype is correct and yes, the datatype in the pandas colomn is a float64 also i have defined the data in the sql table as a float.

Comment: You are trying to put `sql_query_trans_cat` into a data frame, when it's already a data frame. `pd.read_sql_query ` returns an actual data frame. Just work with that, or create a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ajsp for his help:

> You are trying to put sql_query_trans_cat into a data frame, when it's
> already a data frame. pd.read_sql_query  returns an actual data frame.
> Just work with that, or create a copy.

"